# How to get Google chromecast device id from PC Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, deviceid

As Per My knowledge, from the Google official **API document**, 
we can't get device id(which will be used to identify the Google chromecast device) by **JS API** on Receiver APP client, but we can call native api to get the device id of chromecast device on Android(by `CastDevice.getDeviceId()`) and iOS(by `GCKDevice.uniqueID`) client.

We can also to get one receiver device id from PC Chrome browser(by `chrome.cast.Receiver.label`) client, but this device id is different from the ones got from OTT devices and it also may change in some scenarios as mentioned in official **API document**. 
So we can't use it directly.
We also know there is a UDN in the **device-desc.xml** by SSDP, just to call

> http://{chromecast-ip}:8008/ssdp/device-desc.xml.

But we don't know the chromecast-ip programmatically.
Do you have any other idea to get device id on PC chrome browser client? 
Thank you in advance!